# AWS - Connecting 2 VPC regions bi-directional?

Tags: amazon-web-services, site-to-site-vpn

I have 2 VPCs, one in US, one in EU, and each of them have 1 VM.
(IN US there is the Customer GW (set to irish IP) and Virtual Private GW).

I have succesfully connected with openswan from Irish VM,
I can ping Ireland from the US (10.0.0.1)
I cannot ping US from Ireland. Why?

Do I need to set up another VPN connection on US VM to have it fully bidirectional?
I followed tutorial:
https://www.scalefactory.com/blog/2020/12/14/how-to-set-up-a-site-to-site-vpn-connection/

Comment: A VPN is bidirectional. Check your security groups. You haven't given us any information to help you further. If you want more help you will need to post a lot of information - VPN configurations, security groups, NACLs, network diagram, etc.

Comment: It works fine now in 2 directions. Problem was restrictive AWS security groups (access lists). After allowing "any any" traffic problem is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was restrictive AWS security groups (access lists). After allowing "any any" traffic problem is gone.